# Can a generator with rated ouput 2.5kW handle 2 PCs rated 600W and 500W connected to two UPS rated 3000VA/1500W and 2000VA/1200W

Tags: generator, load, watts, ups, pc

I'm having issues with different answers from ChatGPT and Bard. I'm not an expert so I would appreciate an expert opinion.

I have a PC rated 600W connected to a UPS rated 2000VA/1200W with a power factor of 0.6. The UPS is connected to a little generator rated at 800W when there's power outage and it works fine. This has been my setup for sometime now.

I want to add another PC rated at 500W connected to a second UPS rated 3000VA/1500W with a power factor of 0.6.

In this case, I want to place an order for a new generator power output rating of 2800W since my assumption has been that, the UPS draws from the generator only the load amount on it(UPS) plus a little extra for its own internal operation. Although the first little generator is 800W connected to the UPS of 2000VA/1200W, it's able to power the first UPS well (to the best of my knowledge) and I've not had any issue.

So my thinking would be that the two UPS combined load on the generator would 1200W (600W and 500W ) plus extra 50W for each UPS for it's own internal operations.

ChatGPT supports my analysis whilst Google Bard does not.

**ChatGPT**: Total Power Consumption = Power of PC 1 + Power of PC 2 Total Power Consumption = 600W + 500W = 1100W In this case, the total power consumption for both PCs is 1100W, which is well within the capacity of both UPS units (1200W and 1500W). Therefore, a generator with a rated output of 2.5kW should be able to handle these two PCs connected to their respective UPS units without any issues.

**BARD**: No, a generator with rated output 2500W cannot handle two PCs rated 600W and 500W respectively, with each connected to a UPS rated 3000KVA/1500W and 2000VA/1200 W.

The total wattage of the two PCs is 600W + 500W = 1100W. The total wattage of the two UPSs is 1500W + 1200W = 2700W. The total wattage of the two PCs and UPSs is 1100W + 2700W = 3800W. This is more than the rated output of the generator, so the generator cannot handle the load.

Additionally, the VA rating of the UPS is higher than its wattage rating because it takes into account the power factor of the connected devices. The power factor is a measure of how efficiently the devices are using the power. In this case, the UPSs will likely have a power factor of less than 1, which means that they will consume more power than their VA rating suggests. This means that the total wattage of the two PCs and UPSs is likely to be even higher than 3800W. Therefore, the generator will definitely not be able to handle the load.

Any advice on the issue would be appreciate.

Tried google ChatGPT and Bard. However they are all giving different answers so I would like an expert opinion on the matter

Comment: Don't expect correct answers from any LLM--they have no concept of true or false. The entire goal of an LLM, what it's designed to do, is *make text that **sounds** like an answer*. Not text that is an answer, just what *sounds* like one.

Comment: okay. Thank you sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BARD answer is wrong.  It doesn't understand that you will be connecting the computers to the UPSs - it is assuming that the computers and the UPSs will all be connected in parallel to the generator, and that the UPSs and computers will be drawing their full rated power.

If you are connecting the computers to the outputs of the UPSs, and powering the UPSs from the generator, the load on the generator will be the 1100 watts drawn by the computers (and do they really draw that much, or is it just a power supply rating?) and several watts consumed by the UPSs themselves.

I don't know what losses will occur in the UPSs, or how power factor may affect things, but I'd guess the total power requirement would be around 1500 watts, so a 2800 watt generator should be more than adequate.

Comment: The 600W and 500W is the maximum power rating of the PCs but I'm not sure they draw that much. 

I was equally thinking the generatior should be fine since the first gen of 800W power rating was able to power the UPS of 2000VA/1200W connected to the 600W PC. From search, most answers agree that UPS don't draw their full wattage but instead draw the wattage required from the devices connected to it and a little extra for it's own charge operations.

Answer (score 0):

I think both ChatGPT's and Peter Bennett's answers are bases on the hypothesis that the batteries of the UPS are full when you turn on the generator, and that therefore the only power consumption is in the computers (+losses in UPS).

This should be about true if you have a high end system where the generator turns on within a few seconds from the mains power failure. I don't expect this to be the case (those systems are usually in place for quite critical applications like hospitals).

So now, lets assume the batteries of the UPS are partially discharged: when you turn on the generator, it will try to charge both batteries, in addition to power both PCs.

So in a worse case scenario, you have 2*PC + 2*charging batteries + 2*losses. With the data you gave us, there is no way to compute this.

If the UPS have a halfway decent datasheet (or it could be written on them directly), I expect you will find either something like "max input power": you then sum the "max input power" and get an upper bound (which is likely to be very high), or you find something like "max charging power": in this case, your consumption (per UPS) will be max_charging_power+losses+PC_power.

NB: I would assume the batteries recharge more slowly than they can drain (i.e. max UPS power), but it might still be some pretty huge consumption.

If you have no indication about the charging power, but you have the specifications of the battery, you can do some rough estimation:

- take the "C_charge_rating" for your battery (probably between 0.1 and 0.5 for leaded, between 0.25 and 2 for lithium, between 2 and 5 for lithium if they claim fast charging)
- take the capacity C of the battery in Ah
- compute the maximum charge current I_max=C*C_charge_rating
- take the nominal voltage of your battery (V_nom)
- compute the charging power P=V_nom*I_max
- add some margin for losses in the converter (multiply by 1.2 for high end products, by 1.5-2 for low cost)

This should give you a rough estimate of the power used to recharge the batteries.

NB: for the power consumption of the PCs, the power rating is usually a maximal power rating of the supply (so usually you can't ever consume as much (excepted if the supply is underrated for your PC), and you are far bellow when doing simple tasks like going on the internet (without watching movies) or writing some text). On the other hand, don't forget to add the power consumption of your monitor.

Comment: Thank you. I will take that into consideration